# Box positioning styles when resizing browser using IE-CSS3 htc

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, resize

I've been developing with a CSS3 emulator for IE7/8 compatability, this one: http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/

However, whenever I resize the browser, my box positions that are being affected by the HTC file (via the 'behavior' property in my css file) get all whacked out with regard to their positioning and overflow.

They sort of come out of their parent container's width boundaries, change the overflow behavior, etc.

Just wondering if anyone else had experienced this issue with a solution.

I've exhausted many different combinations of the zoom, position:relative, z-index properties on the elements (as well as their parents). No luck.

Answer (score 0):

easiest fix ever.. ditched the ie-css3.htc I was using and implemented PIE instead. Works fine.. much better written to from what I can tell.
http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/